# Redirect to packaged HTML file

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

When using `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, I would like to return a redirect to an HTML file packaged in the extension.

I have the extension activated as a temporary extension.

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
let pattern = "https://developer.mozilla.org/*";
let targetUrl = "/src/index.html";

function redirect(requestDetails) {
  return {
    redirectUrl: targetUrl
  };
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  redirect,
  {urls: [pattern]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

If I use an URL like `https://example.com`, it works. I also tried to use `tabs.update("/src/test.html")` inside the `redirect` function, but no luck.

Do I need some permission for this?

Comment: use browser.runtime.getURL('src/index.html') and declare it in `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it worked! I'll answer my question using your comment, but if you want the solution, you can answer it and I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100771/redirect-to-packaged-html-file?noredirect=1#comment127398882_72100771) comment by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the solution.